# BASH : Issue with passing an array of variables to commands in a for loop

Tags: bash

I am trying to use curl to get a list of files on my ftp server and store that data in a variable to be used with a for loop to download and then delete each file from the ftp server.

the issue is am having is that whist i can get the list of variables out with a simple echo command i cannot get the variables to pass to the curl script properly.

EG.

```
$ while read i; do echo "$i"; done <ftpinputfiles
datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-17-30Z.json
datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-18-00Z.json
datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-18-30Z.json
datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-19-00Z.json
datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-19-30Z.json
datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-20-00Z.json
datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-20-30Z.json
datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-21-00Z.json
datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-21-30Z.json
datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-22-00Z.json
datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-22-30Z.json
datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-23-00Z.json
```

How ever if i run this command to see if the variables are passing to the curl command it does not run properly

```
$ while read i; do echo "ftp://123.123.123.123/Test/$i --user USER:PASS -o $i"; done <ftpinputfiles
 --user admin:PASS -o datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-17- 
 30Z.json
 --user admin:PASS -o datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-18- 
 00Z.json
 --user admin:PASS -o datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-18- 
 30Z.json
 --user admin:PASS -o datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-19- 
 00Z.json
 --user admin:PASS -o datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-19- 
 30Z.json
 --user admin:PASS -o datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-20- 
 00Z.json
 --user admin:PASS -o datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-20- 
 30Z.json
 --user admin:PASS -o datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-21- 
 00Z.json 
 --user admin:PASS -o datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-21- 
 30Z.json
 --user admin:PASS -o datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-22- 
 00Z.json
 --user admin:PASS -o datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-22- 
 30Z.json
 --user admin:PASS -o datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-23- 
 00Z.json
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: that is not formatting the output correctly,

i would expect the output to look like ftp://123.123.123.123/Test/datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-23- 
 00Z.json --user USER:PASS -o datapush_tracked_object_2019-04-28T04-23- 
 00Z.json

but i am only getting the output i have listed at the bottom of the post

Comment: This works fine: `echo "foo" | while read i; do echo "ftp://123.123.123.123/Test/$i --user USER:PASS -o $i"; done`

Comment: Why is there a space before `00Z.json`?

Comment: the space before the 00z.json happened when i copied the output to Stack overflow, its not in the terminal window.

Comment: Then fix it on Stack overflow so we can see what the real problem might be without any red herrings like that. Showing us something that's not exactly what you're looking at is like showing your mechanic your motorcycle and asking him to diagnose the problem with your car.

Comment: My guess is your lines in `ftpinputfiles` end in `\r\n`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45772525/1745001.

Comment: You can get the `read` command to remove a trailing carriage return by using `while IFS=$' \t\n\r' read i;...` Note that this changes `IFS` only for the `read` command itself, so you don't have to set it back to normal afterward.

Comment: Thanks Ed Morton, That solved it, and i can fix the issue with the format above because it is in a comment and i don't think i can edit that comment.